# How nested array in a loop will work

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to understanding the working of this array in a loop

```
for (int answer=0; answer<responses.length; answer++)
{
++frequency[responses[answer]]
}
```

Frequency is an array initialized in start as

```
int [] frequency = new int [6];
```

We also have responses as an array having values `int[] responses= {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4}`

I am not understanding how this `++frequency[responses[answer]]` works, it look to me nested array but how it will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nested arrays. You are just nesting two array access syntaxes.

To explain this code, we first need to know how will the `answer` variable change. From the for loop header, we can see that it starts from 0, and goes all the way up to `responses.length - 1`, which is 8. Now we can evaluate the expression `frequency[responses[answer]]`:

```
// in each iteration of the loop
frequency[responses[0]]
frequency[responses[1]]
frequency[responses[2]]
frequency[responses[3]]
frequency[responses[4]]
frequency[responses[5]]
frequency[responses[6]]
frequency[responses[7]]
```

Now we can evaluate the `responses[x]` part. We just need to find the corresponding response in the `responses` array. `responses[0]` is the first item, which is `1`.

```
frequency[1]
frequency[2]
frequency[3]
frequency[4]
frequency[4]
frequency[4]
frequency[4]
frequency[4]
```

The statement also includes the `++` operator, which increments that particular index of `frequency` by 1. So all of the above indices will be incremented by 1 one after another, making the `frequency` array look like this:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0]
```

On a higher level of abstraction, this code is counting how many times a particular response appears in the `responses` array. For example, `4` appeared 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

The expession

```
++frequency[responses[answer]]
```

is exactly the same as if it had been written

```
int fi = responses[answer];
++frequency[fi];
```

`frequency` has six elements, and all the entries in `responses` are valid indices for a six-element array.  `answers` has eight elements, so as long as `answer` is between 0 and 7, the whole thing will work.